# Is ',' not a valid delimiter in Java?

Tags: java, coordinates, delimiter

I have a coordinate in stored as String in the form x,y, I need to print both of them, so i change the delimiter of my Scanner to ','. When I do this I get the following result:
[image]

The String is inserted correctly and the x-coordinate is also read. What goes wrong here?
CODE:

```
Coordinate addCoordinate(String coordinateString) {
        System.out.print(coordinateString);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(coordinateString);
        Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate();
        in.useDelimiter(",");
        coordinate.x = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print(coordinate.x);
        coordinate.y = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print(coordinate.y);
        return coordinate;
    }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). This also goes for the output of your code.

Comment: The problem is that is that the delimiter pattern needs to match all delimiters.  When you set it to `","` it will match only a single comma as the delimiter.  Whitespace characters (spaces, newlines, etc) will be considered as part of the token.  That will cause `nextInt` to barff ... due to extraneous whitespace at the start or end of the number.  My advice: read the javadocs for `Scanner` *carefully*.

Comment: Ooops ... fixed.

Comment: but that code will not work correctly if the string is, for example, `"2,6\n"` or `"2,6 "` (a newline or a space after the 6) and since `print(coordinateString)` is being used instead of `println`, the newline that we can see in output *must* come from the string

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by [@user16320675](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16320675/user16320675) in his comment, the delimiter won't work as you want for strings like `"2,6\n"` or `"2,6 "`.

You could either start by removing leading and trailing whitespaces contained in `coordinateString`:

```
Coordinate addCoordinate(String coordinateString) {
  coordinateString = coordinateString.trim();
  ...
```

Or use another delimiter that will match a comma or any whitespace character:

```
in.useDelimiter(",|\\s*");
```

Answer (score -1):

Using an extra Scanner did the job.

```
Coordinate readCoordinate(Scanner in) {         
    Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate();
    String coordinateString = in.next();        
    Scanner stringScanner = new Scanner(coordinateString);          
    stringScanner.useDelimiter(",");        
    coordinate.x = stringScanner.nextInt();         
    coordinate.y = stringScanner.nextInt();         
    return coordinate;
}
```

Comment: that is not an answer

Comment: `Coordinate readCoordinate(Scanner in) {
  Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate();
  String coordinateString = in.next();
  Scanner stringScanner = new Scanner(coordinateString);
  stringScanner.useDelimiter(",");
  coordinate.x = stringScanner.nextInt();
  coordinate.y = stringScanner.nextInt();
  return coordinate;
 }`